Is it possible to update UI elements of a page from a different class? (WPF)
This problem originally was "How do you update UI elements from a different class" which I solved with
public static MainWindow window
{
    get
    {
        return Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault()
    }
}

using a line like "MainWindow.window.(ui element to update);" to update the UI element
I decided to try and add pages to my app, which I did with
public MainWindow()
{
    AssemblerGUI assemblerWindow = new AssemblerGUI();
    NavigationFrame.Navigate(assemblerWindow);
}

(NavigationFrame is the name of a Frame element in the xaml)
The pages work, but the above workaround to let other classes modify the UI does not work, and throws "Object reference not set to an instance of the object" whenever its called, because of the page being instantiated for the frame to navigate to it.
I'd guess I could just stick all of the code into the page's .xaml.cs file but that'd be pretty irritating for future me looking to add features
I tried my previous solution, but it throws an error as the page is instantiated (and needs to be for the XAML to work)
public static AssemblerGUI page
{
    get
    {
        return Application.Current.Windows.OfType<AssemblerGUI>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}


I'm curious what problem you're trying to solve with this method of page handling. In general, what do you want the UI to do and what do you mean by allow other classes to update UI elements. This approach doesn't feel very MVVM

What you're talking about is "object life time". If you want your windows to "talk to each other", you have to keep them "alive"; even when switching between pages or windows. That means keeping "references" to the Window objects you create, so you can re-use them. BTW, once you have a reference to a window, you can update the window without even showing it until you're ready. References to other windows is common when doing real-time charting, for example.
